# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip Width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'am trying to make a tooltip with a bigger width.

this is what I have.

HTML

```
<div class="container hidden-sm hidden-xs">
<hr>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills dropup">
                <li class="pull-left"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Sander0542/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li class="pull-left"><a href="https://twitter.com/Sander0542/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li class="pull-left"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/sander0542/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li class="pull-left"><a href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/Sander0542/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></i></a></li>
                <li class="pull-left"><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/+SanderJochems0542" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                <li class="pull-left"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDn9R9Rclc0KVkft_0FewMA" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="/contact"><?php echo $footer["contact"]; ?></a></li>
                <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">© Sander Jochems <?php echo date("Y"); ?></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/sitemap"><?php echo $footer[sitemap]; ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="/privacy"><?php echo $footer[privacy_policy]; ?></a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#language"><?php echo $footer["language"]; ?></a></li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a><i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-fw" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $footer["visitor"]; echo $total_hits; ?>"></i></a></li>
    </ul><br>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%; 
}
```

With this the width wont be bigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just override the default **max-width** of tooltip to what you want.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```css
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 150px !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<br />
<br />
<li class="pull-right"><a><i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-fw" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="I'am trying to make a tooltip with a bigger width."></i></a></li>
```

<sub>**NOTE:** If the containing element is smaller than your *max-width*, then *max-width* won't work.</sub>

in this case you need to append the tooltip to body by adding this :

```
data-container="body"
```

*I hope that helps.. Thanks*